# How can I pass a Scala object reference around in Java?

Tags: java, scala, interop

I want to return from a Java method a reference to a Scala object. How can I do that?

My Scala objects are like this:

```
trait Environment 

object LocalEnvironment extends Environment {...}
object ServerEnvironment extends Environment {...}
```

... and I want my Java method to be like this:

```
Environment getEnvironment() { return LocalEnvironment; }  // DOES NOT COMPILE
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
{ return LocalEnvironment$.MODULE$; }
```

should work.

---

Edit: the reason why this works is that this is how Scala represents singleton objects.  The class `ObjectName$` has a field in it called `MODULE$` that is populated with the single valid instance of that class.  But there is also a class called `ObjectName` that copies all the methods as static methods.  That way you can use it like Java (just call `ObjectName.methodName`) in most cases, and Scala gets to have a real class to pass around.

But when Java needs to pass the class around--not something normally done with a bunch of static methods, which is what `object` is designed to emulate in Java--you then have to know how Scala represents it internally.

Comment: Some explanation would be good. Is this a 'portable' method, or are the $'s an implementation artifact of Scala ?

Comment: @Brian - I've partially answered in the edit.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'portable' in contrast to 'implementation artifact'.  It's both--Scala uses a consistent naming scheme for its implementation artifacts.  Unlike anonymous closures, this one is easy to predict.

Comment: Given `LocalEnvironment` seems to be a standalone singleton object, it should probably be `return LocalEnvironment.MODULE$` (no `$` in `LocalEnvironment`).

Comment: @Fabian - That doesn't work.  The `LocalEnvironment` class will contain exactly and only those static methods needed to copy the (non-static) methods in the Scala singleton.  `MODULE$` is not one of those methods--it is a field of the `LocalEnvironment$` class that is instantiated in a single copy (i.e. `LocalEnvironment$` is the class that contains implementation details, and `MODULE$` is an implementation detail within it).

Answer (score 24):

While the $.MODULE$ method works, a slightly less jarring way to get Java-interop with Scala objects is to expose the object as a method on itself.

The Scala:

```
object LocalEnvironment extends Environment{
   def instance = this
}
```

The Java:

```
Environment getEnvironment() { return LocalEnvironment.instance(); }
```

This works because under the covers, .instance() is implemented as a static method on class LocalEnvironment.   There has been some discussion about Scala objects getting an "instance" method by default, for just this purpose.

Comment: This is cool, but it would need some comments to explain the purpose of the variable. For that reason, I've gone with the MODULE$ thing instead.

Comment: Agreed, cool and +1, but only works if you have write access to the Object's source. Will not work for scala.xml.TopScope, for example.