# How can I use a Scala singleton object in Java?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have a Scala object that I need to use in a Java class.

Here's the Scala object

```
object Person {
  val MALE = "m"
  val FEMALE = "f"
}
```

How can I use this Scala object in Java?

I have tried the following so far without success (compile errors):

- `Person.MALE()` //returns a String which is useless as I want the actual Person object

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a Scala object reference around in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845737/how-can-i-pass-a-scala-object-reference-around-in-java)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use `Person$.MODULE$`. See also

- [How can I pass a Scala object reference around in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845737/how-can-i-pass-a-scala-object-reference-around-in-java)
- [Singletons as Synthetic classes in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721046/singletons-as-synthetic-classes-in-scala)

---

**Edit**: A working example (I checked, it compiles and works):
Scala:

```
object Person {
  val MALE = "m";
}
```

Java counterpart:

```
public class Test {
    Person$ myvar = Person$.MODULE$;

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        System.out.println(new Test().myvar.MALE());
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really work either. Eclipse tells me:
    **Person$ cannot be resolved to a variable'code**

and the code doesn't compile

Comment: @user786045, you need to add an import statement for Person$ manually. Eclipse does not add it automatically on "organize imports".

Answer (score 1):

In case you use a `package object`, the access is a bit different

Scala:

```
package my.scala.package

package object Person {
  val MALE = "m";
}
```

Java counterpart:

```
public static void main() {
  System.out.println(my.scala.package.Person.package$.MODULE$.MALE);
}
```