# Access inner class method with "fine" syntax in Java using Scala class & object

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I have the following scala example:

```
class Nested {}
object Nested {
  class Inner {}
  object Inner {
    def x = 321
  }
}
```

With a JUnit test to test specifically that I can do `Nested.Inner.x()` and call the method freely without the `Nested.Inner$.MODULE$.x()`:

```
  import static junit.framework.Assert.*;
  import org.junit.Test;

  public class TestFromJava {

  @Test
  public void accessTest() {
    assertEquals(321, Nested.Inner.x());
  }
}
```

This compiles, but at the moment of running the test, I am getting (`sbt test`):

```
[error] TestFromJava.java:8: cannot find symbol
[error]   symbol:   method x()
[error]   location: class Nested.Inner
[error] Nested.Inner.x
```

How can I benefit from both Scala syntax and not using the horrible $? Maybe it is a feature of the language as how it generates the `object` instances.

Comment: What do you mean by "this compiles"? Is that a runtime error you are showing? Looks like you are using sbt. Did you succeed to run `sbt test:compile`? I think you pretty much do need to access that symbol through `Nested.Inner$.MODULE$.x()`

Comment: Compiles meaning `sbt clean compile` succeeds.

Comment: But where is `TestFromJava`, is that main sources or test sources? Is that in `src/main/java` or `src/test/java` (assuming you have an sbt build - can you confirm this?). `compile` does not compile test-sources, it's short for `compile:compile`. You need to run `test:compile`.

Comment: Which scala version is this? If I recall you don't need the `$MODULE` for 2.11.

Comment: @0__ on `sbt test:compile` it complains about the same compilation error from above. @yw3410 2.11.7 scala version

Comment: q.e.d. - you can _not_ access those objects from Java without resolving the module fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to qualify singleton `object` access when calling from Java, as [explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284028/how-can-i-use-a-scala-singleton-object-in-java).

In your case that would be

```
Nested.Inner$.MODULE$.x()
```