# Unable to import a Scala object into the Java project

Tags: java, scala

I created a Scala `object`:

```
package myapp.data

import java.io.File
import myapp.models.NodeViewModel
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver

object ForumSerializer {
    def openFile(file : File) : NodeViewModel = {
        // doing something
    }

    def saveToFile(model : NodeViewModel) : Unit = {
        // doing something
    }
}
```

Then I tried to import it in another Java file

```
import myapp.ForumSerializer;
```

The error I get is:

```
Import myapp.ForumSerializer cannot be resolved.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284028/how-can-i-use-a-scala-singleton-object-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import it as `ForumSerializer$`.
Scala adds a `$`, so the compiler doesn't get confused with the class, when you have both an object and a class of the same name. You can then access the singleton object using the generated `MODULE$`.