# Range class : java interoperability

Tags: java, scala, interop

Why does not this work? In a Java code:

```
import scala.collections.immutable.Range;

// ...

Range r = Range.apply(0, 10)
```

Eclipse says:

> The method apply(int) in the type Range is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)

And SBT says:

> error: method apply in class Range cannot be applied to given types;

However, there *is* an apply(Int, Int) method in the collections.immutable.Range object of the Scala API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're calling the `apply(int)` method **from the [`Range` *class*](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range)**. You should be calling **`apply(int,int)` from [the *companion object*](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range$):**

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Range$;
// ...
Range r = Range$.MODULE$.apply(0, 10)
```

See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845737/how-can-i-pass-a-scala-object-reference-around-in-java) for general info.

Comment: Yeah, but normally scalac will generate static forwarders for companion object methods. In this case however, it cannot, because `Range` class already contains a method named `apply` (regardless of the fact that it has different signature).

Comment: More details on why static forwarder is not generated: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/FeXSYcAv2ho

Comment: Thanks, I will just add a Java interop object to my API/DSL to circumvent this. I don't want my users to write such things as `Range$.MODULE$.apply` all over the place.