# How to pass nested scala object reference in Java?

Tags: java, scala, interop

There have been some questions answered on this before.

- [How can I pass a scala object reference around in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845737/how-can-i-pass-a-scala-object-reference-around-in-java)
- [How can I use a Scala singleton object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284028/how-can-i-use-a-scala-singleton-object-in-java)

But my problem is that I have nested scala objects, something like:

```
object Criteria {
    object ActionCriteria {
        case class Action (parameter: String) {
            def this(parameter: String) = { this(paramerter) }
        }

        object Action {
           def apply(parameter: String): Action = { apply(parameter) }
        } 
    }
}
```

In java I then need to create a list of Actions. I have tried this... to no avail:

```
import Criteria.ActionCriteria.Action$

....

List<Criteria.ActionCriteria.Action$.MODULE$> actions = new ArrayList<>();
```

As well as a bunch of other combinations like adding $.MODULE$ with every object. Right now I am getting the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol Criteria.ActionCriteria
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
List<Criteria$ActionCriteria$Action> actions = new ArrayList<>();
```

Seems to work fine. Found this with Scala REPL:

```scala
scala> classOf[Criteria.ActionCriteria.Action]
res1: Class[Criteria.ActionCriteria.Action] = class Criteria$ActionCriteria$Action
```

If you want the type of `Action` object, not case class (highly unlikely, but for the sake of completeness):

```scala
scala> Criteria.ActionCriteria.Action.getClass
res2: Class[_ <: Criteria.ActionCriteria.Action.type] = class Criteria$ActionCriteria$Action$
```

The difference is caused by Scala expecting `Action` to be a type in `classOf[Action]`, so it returns the type corresponding to the case class. When you use `Action` in a context where a value is expected, it returns the singleton instance instead, so you can call standard Java method `getClass` to get the type of `object Action`.

In case you need other types:

```java
Criteria$                       cm    = Criteria$.MODULE$;
Criteria.ActionCriteria$        cacm  = Criteria.ActionCriteria$.MODULE$;
Criteria$ActionCriteria$Action$ cacam = Criteria$ActionCriteria$Action$.MODULE$;
Criteria$ActionCriteria$Action  caca  = new Criteria$ActionCriteria$Action("Foo");
```

`Criteria.ActionCriteria$` is breaking the pattern here. Why? According to Iulian Dragos' comment under [bug SI-2034](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2034) this is a special case:

> since objects are "the equivalent of static" in the Java world, we
>   wanted to make it easier for Java code to use static inner classes.
>   When there's only one level of nesting, there's a guaranteed
>   companion: every top-level object gets a mirror class (if there isn't
>   one) that creates static forwarders to module methods (that's how one
>   can run a `main` method defined inside an object). Therefore, a
>   special case for one-level nesting: those classes use the flattened
>   name (without a `$` suffix) as outer_name. So, Java code can say `new Outer.Inner`.

---

#### Summary

- For every level of nesting other than first you replace `.` with `$` in your class names
- If the target type is also an object you add `$` at the end
- If you want an instance you add `.MODULE$`